# What is the definition of embedding? (pde)

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I see the definition in book which tells that:
If we say linear space $A$ is embedding in $B$, it means $A$ is contained in $B$ and the mapping $A\to B$ is continuous.

But I also see the definition in wiki which tells that:
the mapping $A\to B$ is injective.

What is exactly the definition of embedding? I'm confused of it.
Thank you!

Comment: There are many concepts that have different definitions used by different authors. Usually they are equivalent, but in this case there are subtle differences (such as one requiring that $A\subseteq B$ and the other doesn't). They convey the same idea, and it's not difficult to translate between them, but they are not the same.

Comment: finally figure out, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ is contained in $B$, then the mapping
$$
f:A\to B,\qquad a\mapsto a
$$
will always be injective.

As for the definition of embedding, there are variants: some require that $f$ is continuous, and some do not require this property.
In the latter case, they use the term "continuous embedding" to denote the case that $f$ is continuous.

Comment: so there is a difference between embedding and continues embedding. Embedding means $A$ is contained in $B$ (which is equal to: $f$ is injective). Moreover, continues embedding means $f$ also need to be continues(or equally, bounded). Am I  right? thank you very much!

Comment: @hongjinwu yes i would agree with that, and continuous and bounded are equivalent in this context, as you said (I guess Arthur is thinking about something different or about a more general case).

Comment: yes, according to a theorem which is: normed linear spaces A,B , $f: A \rightarrow$ B is continues $\Leftrightarrow f$ is bounded.

Comment: @supinf I was introducing myself to these notions too, and I was confused with continuity thinking of it in the traditional sense of $\epsilon-\delta$ or the topological definition. Could you explain me how we deduce continuity from boundedness? Or is it only by definition for embeddings?

Comment: @ares a linear operator is bounded iff it is continuous. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_operator. If you search, you will probably find proofs on math.SE